# I get Error messages when entering date values into column with Date data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used the following query to insert values. The `DateOfLoan` data type is `date`. There is an extra column in my table called `DateDueBack` and this column is a computed column which adds 14 days to the date in the `DateOfLoan` column.

```
Insert CurrentLoans(LoanID, BookISBN, MemberID, DateOfLoan)
Values  (101, 'MB00001', 2, '20/10/2014'),
        (102, 'AO00001', 5, '13/10/2014'),
        (103, 'AH00002', 5, '13/10/2014'),
        (104, 'DK10100', 2, '23/10/2014'),
        (105, 'EP00666', 1, '12/10/2014'),
        (106, 'HH10189', 4, '01/01/2014');
```

I get the following error message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

When I remove the quotes around the date values I get an error message saying Int is incompatible with `Date`.

Can someone explain whats wrong with the code above and provide a solution.

Thanks in advance for any help offerd.

Comment: The default date format of database is yyyy-mm-dd (2015-02-20) and you are inserting in dd/mm/yyyy (13/10/2014) format

Comment: Plz give correct answers in answers section. So that the user can mark it answer.

Comment: format should be **YYYY-MM-DD**

Comment: How do I change the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date format Should be use in sql-server like below format.

```
 YYYY-MM-dd or MM/dd/YYYY
```

So, you have to try like this.

```
Insert CurrentLoans(LoanID, BookISBN, MemberID, DateOfLoan)
Values  (101, 'MB00001', 2, '10/20/2014')
```

or

```
Insert CurrentLoans(LoanID, BookISBN, MemberID, DateOfLoan)
Values  (101, 'MB00001', 2, '2014-10-20')
```

Or use Sql [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
 Insert CurrentLoans(LoanID, BookISBN, MemberID, DateOfLoan)
 Values  (101, 'MB00001', 2,convert(date,'20/10/2014',103))
```

Comment: if i use the convert method, can i search for dates using 20/10/14

Comment: i used the convert function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Insert into CurrentLoans(LoanID,BookISBN,MemberID,DateOfLoan)
Values  (101, 'MB00001', 2, '2014-10-20'),
        (102, 'AO00001', 5, '2014-10-13'),
        (103, 'AH00002', 5, '2014-1013'),
        (104, 'DK10100', 2, '2014-10-23'),
        (105, 'EP00666', 1, '2014-10-12'),
        (106, 'HH10189', 4, '2014-01-01');
```

Answer (score 0):

The default date format SQL Server can vary by location. Out of the box, it is mm/dd/yyyy, although other formats (such as yyyy-mm-dd can be processed, as suggested in the question comments).

[KB article 173907](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/173907) explains this.

With a date string of '20/10/2014', SQL thinks you are specifying a date of the 10th day of 20th month of 2014, which isn't valid, so it rejects your input.

However, you can use the [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function to be more explicit in your code, which takes defaults and location out of the equation.

```
-- format 103 = dd/mm/yyyy

Insert CurrentLoans(LoanID, BookISBN, MemberID, DateOfLoan)
Values  (101, 'MB00001', 2, convert(datetime, '20/10/2014', 103)),
        (102, 'AO00001', 5, convert(datetime, '13/10/2014', 103)),
        (103, 'AH00002', 5, convert(datetime, '13/10/2014', 103)),
        (104, 'DK10100', 2, convert(datetime, '23/10/2014', 103)),
        (105, 'EP00666', 1, convert(datetime, '12/10/2014', 103)),
        (106, 'HH10189', 4, convert(datetime, '01/01/2014', 103));
```

Comment: would this convert function have to be used on every occasion when you have dates to enter.

Comment: It is a risk-free approach - the conversion format applies only to the statement. Using `SET DATEFORMAT DMY`, for example, applies the setting to the batch, which may contain multiple statements, which may not use the same date format. If you know what format your date strings are, then the `SET DATEFORMAT` approach may be easier to use. However, there are some 'gotchas' with it. The document at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx says that *Some character strings formats, for example ISO 8601, are interpreted independently of the DATEFORMAT setting.*

Comment: Sorry - not sure that answers your question. Bottom line is - yes - if your date strings are not in the same format as the database default, you will need to handle formatting in each statement in which string->datetime conversion happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your default settings appear to be `MONTH-DAY-YEAR`, so SQL Server is trying to convert `'20/10/2014'` into the 10th day of the 20th month, and there are only 12 months so you are getting an error.

A simple fix would be to explictly set your `DATEFORMAT`, this works fine:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT  CONVERT(DATE, '20/10/2014');
```

A better solution would be to use a culture invariant format, the other answers are suggesting the ISO format `yyyy-MM-dd`, but although this will work in your case I do not advocate it.

The reason is for whatever reason the ISO format is **not** culture invariant for the `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME` datatypes. The following yeilds a conversion error:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY; 
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-02-20');
```

It is only invariant for the new `DATE` and `DATETIME2` datatypes. I frequently see this suggested because it is the ISO format, and it is still easily readible for the human eye, and if you happen to work on servers with default settings of `MDY` most of the time you will get away with it for the most part.

But if you want things to work all the time, not most of the time then the **only** invariant format for `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME` is `yyyyMMdd`, as such I would advise using this, as it is invariant for all types.

For further reading Aaron Bertrand has written a great article on it: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)